# how to Abbreviated jquery event?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jquery action apply on a div based (which i select the div and apply action but i hve 90 div ) on its ID how to Abbreviated this statements :
Here is the code

```
if ($('#justgarph > p:contains("draggable1")').length > 0) {
    $(".product").animate({
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0"
    }, 500).delay(100);

    $("#draggable1").animate({
        "top": "-300px",
        "left": "200px"
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#draggable1").animate({
            "top": "-106px",
            "left": "470px"
        }, 1000);
        $("#draggable1").addClass("activeproduct")
    }, 800);
}

if ($('#justgarph > p:contains("draggable2")').length > 0) {
    $(".product").animate({
        "top": "0",
        "left": "0"
    }, 500).delay(100);

    $("#draggable2").animate({
        "top": "-300px",
        "left": "100px"
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#draggable2").animate({
            "top": "-106px",
            "left": "320px"
        }, 1000);

        $("#draggable2").addClass("activeproduct")
    }, 800);
}
```

Comment: is the `left` param different "470px" and "320px"

Comment: If that's the case, you'd need it as a second param @ArunPJohny. My solution would not be possible any more unless there is a way to calculate the `left`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build a loop and make the ID dynamic. The only thing that changes if I see this correctly is the ID.

```
// make them all draggable 'at once' if they all have the same left values
for (var i=0; i<90; i++) {
  if ($('#justgarph > p:contains("draggable"' + i + ')').length > 0) {
      $(".product").animate({
          "top": "0",
          "left": "0"
      }, 500).delay(100);

      $("#draggable" + i).animate({
          "top": "-300px",
          "left": "200px"
      }, 500);

      setTimeout(function () {
          $("#draggable" + i).animate({
              "top": "-106px",
              "left": "470px"
          }, 1000);
          $("#draggable" + i).addClass("activeproduct")
      }, 800);
  }
}
```

In case the changing `left` values are intentional, you're better off with putting the whole thing in a function. Your code will be a bit longer than the above. But it can only work in the loop if all are the same.

So here, you've got a function around all of it with three params. The first is the `id` as text with a `#`, and the second and third are the two changing `left` values in `px` without the `px`.

```
function makeDraggable(id, l1, l2) {
  if ($('#justgarph > p:contains(' + e + ')').length > 0) {
      $(".product").animate({
          "top": "0",
          "left": "0"
      }, 500).delay(100);

      $(e).animate({
          "top": "-300px",
          "left": l1 + "px"
      }, 500);

      setTimeout(function () {
          $(e).animate({
              "top": "-106px",
              "left": l2 + "px"
          }, 1000);
          $(e).addClass("activeproduct")
      }, 800);
  }
}

// make them all draggable, one at a time
makeDraggable('#draggable1', 100, 470);
makeDraggable('#draggable2', 200, 320);
```

Comment: won't work because the `left` value in the timeout portion is different

Comment: That's not really a very helpful comment @Medhat. Is there an error message? Which part does not work? Have you tried playing around with it?